# Why Doctrine don't return my values in array?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I have an entity `NewsVersion` with ManyToMany :

```
class NewsVersion
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var NewsCategory[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(
     *     targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\NewsCategory",
     *     cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="news_version_categories")
     */
    private $categories;

    ...
```

In my repository, when I call this :

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('nv')
        ->select('nv')
        ->innerJoin('nv.categories', 'nvc')
        ->addSelect('nvc');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I have :

[image]

But When I call this :

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('nv')
        ->select('nv')
        ->innerJoin('nv.categories', 'nvc')
        ->addSelect('nvc.id');
```

I have :

[image]

Why `nvc.id` don't return `id` in `categories` array ? I want return only id from my category, but in `categories` array in `NewsVersion` entity (same as first screen)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no soluce

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `->addSelect('nvc.id')`

and add the id of category in the select statement

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('nv')
        ->select('nv', 'nvc.id')
        ->innerJoin('nv.categories', 'nvc');
```

Comment: This same ^^ My question is : Why nvc.id don't return id in categories array ? I want return only id from my category, but in  categories array in NewsVersion entity (same as first screen). Thanks :)

Comment: You cann't merge the id category  in the categories array

Answer (score 0):

You're making two separate queries for data; `$queryBuilder->addSelect()` creates a new one alongside the first.

It might make sense in plain SQL.

```
/* ->select('nv') */
SELECT *
FROM `nv`
/* all of nv's fields are returned in this set */

/* ->addSelect('nvc.id') */
SELECT `id`
FROM `nvc`
/* only nvc.id is returned in this set */
```

`Doctrine` wraps all of the queries' resultsets in an array, for your convenience, but doesn't combine them because **they did not come from the same query**.

Relevant [source](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html#787-813):

```
// class QueryBuilder
public function addSelect($select = null)
{
    // ...
    return $this->add('select', new Expr\Select($selects), true);
}
```